# Angular Dart: material input initial value

Tags: templates, dart, angular-material, angular-dart

I am using angular dart to create a web application.

I have a page where i use material input to get input from the user. in that, i need to have a default initial value in the text box as soon as the page is loaded.

I don't want to bind the input to any variable as this is just a one time use and i will not need binding from component to template after this.

is there a way to specify default/initial value for 'material-input' in dart?

Comment: "I don't want to bind the input to any variable as this is just a one time use" how will you handle user input? I think you need to bind to a variable.

Comment: `<material-input ngModel="default initial value">`

Comment: i solved it using [ngModel]="value". Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `hintText`.

```
<material-input hintText="Initial value">
</material-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the notes above:

```
<material-input [ngModel]="value">
```

Was the solution he used. This will push the value into the input without having it be a two way variable. Nate's suggestion of using hintText is also a good use of this.